# ASP.NET MVC Parial views and layouts in Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Is it possible for a partial view to have a layout so that whenever the partial is rendered - it is rendered with its own layout ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can have a layout for a partial, just make sure your layout is not defining the header and the body sections of your html (because it's for a partial).

here is a sample:

_partialViewLayout.cshtml

```
<div class="partial-view-container">
  @RenderSection("partialViewContent", true)
</div>
```

partialView.cshtml

```
@{
  Layout = "~/_partialViewLayout.cshtml";
}

@section partialViewContent {
  <div></div>
}
```